# Collapse a dataframe pandas after grouping

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have the following Dataframe:

```
    between_count            name1            name2  \
0              1     Jacubo Hakym  Johannem Haxixe   
1              2  Johannem Haxixe          Antonio   
2              4          Antonio  Johannem Haxixe   
3              8  Johannem Haxixe     Jacubo Hakym   
4             13     Jacubo Hakym  Johannem Haxixe   
5             24  Johannem Haxixe           Domine   
6             44           Domine  Johannem Haxixe   
7             20  Johannem Haxixe  Johannem Haxixe   
8             48  Johannem Haxixe  Johannem Haxixe   

                                               words  
0                          contra Pro Coram magistro  
1                Coram magistro contra Axac testibus  
2  Axac testibus Testamur quod Coram magistro hab...  
3  habitator Rabatj Melite Jn accomandita dederat...  
4  duas taceas de argento Hodie supratitulato pre...  
5  presenti unam taceam ex dictis duabus taceis e...  
6  speravi Jn te’ et nomine vendicionis dimisit p...  
7  venditor confessus est se recepisse at habuiss...  
8  venditor transtulit et mandavit Jn eumdem magi...
```

I would like the group by name1 and name2 in this way:

```
cp = candidate_pairs.groupby(['name1','name2'], as_index=False).apply(func)
```

But at  the same time add the between_count of the grouped items and append the words to one bow.

Therefore record 0 and 4 would become:
between_count            name1            name2            words
14                       Jacubo Hakym     Johannem Haxixe  contra Pro Coram magistro duas taceas de argento Hodie supratitulato pre...

Is there an easy way to do this rather than doing it manually with adding the values of between_count and appending the words and deleting the unwanted rows? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need aggreagte by `sum` and by `join` with [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
d = {'between_count':'sum', 'words':' '.join}
cp = candidate_pairs.groupby(['name1','name2'], as_index=False).agg(d)
print (cp)
             name1            name2  between_count  \
0          Antonio  Johannem Haxixe              4   
1           Domine  Johannem Haxixe             44   
2     Jacubo Hakym  Johannem Haxixe             14   
3  Johannem Haxixe          Antonio              2   
4  Johannem Haxixe           Domine             24   
5  Johannem Haxixe     Jacubo Hakym              8   
6  Johannem Haxixe  Johannem Haxixe             68   

                                               words  
0     Axac testibus Testamur quod Coram magistro hab  
1     speravi Jn te’ et nomine vendicionis dimisit p  
2  contra Pro Coram magistro duas taceas de argen...  
3                Coram magistro contra Axac testibus  
4     presenti unam taceam ex dictis duabus taceis e  
5     habitator Rabatj Melite Jn accomandita dederat  
6  venditor confessus est se recepisse at habuiss...
```